# Do Non-fungible and Fungible tokens work together in applications?

Tags: tokens, nft

I am developing an application and wish to make implement NFT. For example, I want to sell and buy online virtual items. For example, I have an item A that will have 100 NFTs. Does a user buy those NFTs with with FTs? Say a user registers an account and gets 100 Fungible tokens, TestCoin. And each of the NFTs will cost one TestCoin each. The user can then pay 10 TestCoins to buy 10 NFTs of item A.

Is this a typical scenario of how it would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use both NFTs and FTs in the same application. As you described, it is common for users to purchase NFTs using FTs.

Comment: Hey thank you so much. I really appreciate the answer. I wanted to upvote your answer, but I couldn't because I need 15 reputation points.

Comment: No problem :D, happy to help! If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: do you know any games that use "in-game currency" to purchase NFT's ?